# css, how to stop an element being squashed by container

Tags: html, css, styles

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvXsQ/1/)

I want to stop the `.outer` from changing shape/size when the window is resized to be narrower than `.outer`s contents by only applying style directly to `.outer` if that is possible.

HTML:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner' style='background:#f00'>
    </div>
    <div class='inner' style='background:#0f0'>
    </div>
    <div class='inner' style='background:#00f'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer, .inner{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.outer{
    /*what to put in here*/
}

.inner{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

in the jsfiddle if you resize the result panel to be thinner, you will see the blue get pushed on to the next row, followed by the green square, I would like the outer to maintain its original shape/size so the three `.inner`s maintain their positions.

Comment: You can add a `width` to your `.outer`.

Comment: P.S - Notice that if you set both `floating` and `display: inline-block` to the same element, the inline block setting won't do anything and the element will be rendered as a floating block.

Comment: @putvande true, i should have stated that the soltion needs to be generic, i.e. for content of any size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Setting a minimal width to the container**

Use the [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) property

```
.outer{
    min-width:150px;
}
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/xvXsQ/2/)

---

**Using the inline-block display abilities**

A more flexible way would be to use properties such as [`word-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) and [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), taking advantage of the `inline-block` display:

```
.outer{
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: -1em;
}
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/xvXsQ/4/)

Comment: 2nd one was the winner, I won't always know how big the content is in `.outer`

Comment: @Italy could I ask what the `-1em` does ? or why it is necessary for this solution

Comment: @0xor1 My name is Itay :). You can just remove it and see. When using `inline-block` display on elements, they're being rendered similarly to words. When you put white spaces (or line breaks) in your code between words (like you have between your div's), the browsers renders a white space between every two elements. The word-spacing walk around this and making these spaces invisible (of course you have to give the child elements `word-spacing: normal` so you can write normal text there.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't "only applying style directly to `.outer`". But it is another option. Getting rid of `float: left`, changing `width` to `min-width` and adding `display: table-cell` on `.inner` gives the desired result.

**CSS**

```
.outer, .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.inner {
    min-width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvXsQ/6/)**</kbd> showing this approach.